# Mongoid includes not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Good day!

I'm trying to load model for mongoDB with this:

```
User.includes(:party).first
```

In debug mode for mongoid I see next requests:

```
D, [2015-12-19T13:53:19.354800 #3847] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{}}
D, [2015-12-19T13:53:19.355403 #3847] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | SUCCEEDED | 0.000451s
D, [2015-12-19T13:53:19.366237 #3847] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | STARTED | {"find"=>"parties", "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$in"=>[nil]}}}
D, [2015-12-19T13:53:19.366626 #3847] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | SUCCEEDED | 0.000307s
```

As you can see second request performed with this params:

```
{"find"=>"parties", "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$in"=>[nil]}}}
```

I can't figure out why, here is my models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :nickname,              type: String
  field :email,                 type: String

  has_one :party
  has_many :added_songs,        class_name: 'Playlist::Song'
  has_many :chat_messages,      class_name: 'Chat::Message'
end

class Party
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :active,    type: Boolean,    default: true
  field :title,     type: String

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :chat, class_name: 'Party::Chat'
  has_one :playlist, class_name: 'Party::Playlist'
end
```

And the interesting part is that if I do:

```
Party.includes(:user).first
```

It works fine. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not necessarily specified what "it works" means but I assume you just mean that it actually returns a document from the database. As far as I can tell your eager load is working as intended.

You are specifying that `User` has one `Party`. That means the `user_id` is stores in the `Party`, and that `party_id` is **not** stored in `User`.

So when you run this query:

```
User.includes(:party).first
```

It will specifically look for the `Party` objects that do not have a specific `User`:

```
"find"=>"parties", "filter"=>{"user_id"=>{"$in"=>[nil]}}
```

So if you do the reverse:

```
Party.includes(:user).first
```

It is **not** capable of doing this:

```
"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"party_id"=>{"$in"=>[nil]}}
```

Because there is no `party_id` stored in the `User` collection.

So if you want to run `User.includes(:party).first` you should try finding a specific `User` first, something like:

```
User.where(:_id => "one of your users").includes(:party).first
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need!